# unable to mount /vagrant in Solaris box

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, solaris

I created a `vagrantfile` and downloaded `solaris` box. During `vagrant up` command, I'm getting the below error.

```
 default: /vagrant => C:/Users/w726901/Desktop/solaris The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

sudo chown `/usr/xpg4/bin/id -u vagrant`:`/usr/xpg4/bin/id -g vagrant` /vagrant

Stdout from the command:

Stderr from the command: chown: /vagrant: Invalid argument
```

Versions used:

> Vagrant - 1.8.4
>   VirtualBox - 4.3.18
>   Solaris - solaris-11.2.box

The Vagrantfile is :

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "solaris"
  config.vm.network "public_network"
 end
```

Solaris Box link : http://www.benden.us/vagrant/solaris-11.2.box

How to fix this issue.

Comment: Please provide the `vagrantfile`, and a link to the `solaris-11.2.box` file you used.

Comment: kindly help me to fix this